# Highcharts - columnrange - How to prevent dataLabels formatter from triggering several times per data (series)?

Tags: reactjs, charts, highcharts

I have a datetime chart which supposed to show some time intervals. I needed to add some labels to each time interval which shows some data from the array I pass to chart. But the problem is: the more elements I have in the array, the weirder behaviour I get. Datalabels overlapping each other and rendering at the columns they should not be rendered at. I found out that the `formatter` triggers multiple times, and I want to find out is there any way to prevent this behaviour and render datalabels only once per `data`.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```js
chart: {
        type: 'columnrange',
        margin: 0,
        inverted: true,
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        events: {
          load: function (ctx) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
              this.addSeries({
                type: 'columnrange',
                grouping: false,
                data: [
                  {
                    low: i < data.filter(x => x.rowNumber === 4).length
                      ? data.filter(x => x.rowNumber === 4)[i].intervalStart
                      : Date.UTC(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0),
                    high: i < data.filter(x => x.rowNumber === 4).length
                      ? data.filter(x => x.rowNumber === 4)[i].intervalEnd
                      : Date.UTC(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0),
                    color: i < data.filter(x => x.rowNumber === 4).length
                      ? (data.filter(x => x.rowNumber === 4)[i].status === 1 ? "#6ebb86" : "#434348")
                      : "transparent",
                    dataLabels: {
                      enabled: true,
                      verticalAlign: 'middle',
                      align: 'center',
                      inside: true,
                      crop: true,
                      style: {
                        fontSize: '14px',
                      },

                      formatter: (e) => {
                        return i < data.filter(x => x.rowNumber === 4).length
                          ? data.filter(x => x.rowNumber === 4)[i]?.dataLabel
                          : ""
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ],
                borderColor: 'transparent',
              });
            }
          },
        },
      },
```

[image: The example of dataLabels overlapping and mismatch]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution and I want to share it with others.

Instead of writing `dataPoints` in the `load` function, I decided to move it to `plotOptions` -> `series` so that from there I could access the `series` itself. This is what it looks like:

```js
plotOptions: {
        columnrange: {
          grouping: false,
          pointPadding: -0.2,
          states: {
            hover: {
              borderColor: 'transparent',
            },
            inactive: {
              enabled: false,
            },
          },
        },
        series: {
          cursor: 'pointer',
          point: {
            events: {
              click: function () {
                triggerEditInterval(
                  this.series.chart.hoverPoint?.options.low!,
                  this.series.chart.hoverPoint?.options.high!)
              },
            }
          },
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            align: 'center',
            inside: true,
            crop: true,
            style: {
              fontSize: '14px',
            },

            formatter: function () {
              var actualPoints = this.series.points.filter(p => typeof p.y === 'number'); //getting the list of actual points

              if (this.y === actualPoints.find(x => x.y === this.y)?.y) { // if the y of current point exists in our actual points list
                if (actualPoints.findIndex(x => x.y === this.y)! === 0) { // check if actual point is first category
                  return data.find(x => x.intervalEnd === this.y && x.rowNumber === 4)?.dataLabel // return the label of element from our data element with appropriate coordinates and rowNumber for first category
                }
                else {
                  return data.find(x => x.intervalEnd === this.y && x.rowNumber === 5)?.dataLabel // else return the element with rowNumber for second category
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
      },
```

[image: It works just as intended]